# Cannot run docker without sudo on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on WSL2

Tags: ubuntu, docker, wsl2

https://github.com/sindresorhus/guides/blob/main/docker-without-sudo.md

Found this doc on how to run docker without sudo, but it doesn't work for some reason. I have no idea why.

```
sudo groupadd docker

sudo gpasswd -a $USER docker

sudo service docker restart
```

I ran these three commands on WSL Ubuntu and I cannot do docker run hello-world without sudo.

```
admin@PC-SE-L3056:~$ docker run hello-world
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at tcp://localhost:2375. Is the docker daemon running?.
See 'docker run --help'.
admin@PC-SE-L3056:~$ sudo docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
cd latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
b8dfde127a29: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:0fe98d7debd9049c50b597ef1f85b7c1e8cc81f59c8d623fcb2250e8bec85b38
Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest

Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
 1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
 2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
    (amd64)
 3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
    executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
 4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
    to your terminal.

To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
 $ docker run -it ubuntu bash

Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker ID:
 https://hub.docker.com/

For more examples and ideas, visit:
 https://docs.docker.com/get-started/
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on WSL2.

The user admin belongs to:

```
admin : admin adm dialout cdrom floppy sudo audio dip video plugdev netdev docker
```

I restarted WSL2 using `wsl --shutdown` on Powershell.

Comment: When you ran `sudo gpasswd -a $USER docker`, you actually ran `sudo gpasswd -a admin docker1`, correct?  Can you display which groups `admin` are assigned to?  You will also want to shutdown and restart the WSL2 instance after running that command.  You could also try `sudo usermod -aG docker admin'

Comment: Has of 2020 [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/477551/how-can-i-use-docker-without-sudo) seems like more complete information.  Information from 2014 contained in answers from 2014 are likely no longer relevant.